# File not found exception - windows phone

Tags: c#, exception, windows-phone-8, file-io, windows-phone

I am trying to integrate Google oAuth 2.0 in my windows phone app.My client_secret.json file in the root directory of my project and its build action is set to content.
Here is my code

```
 var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                   new FileStream("../client_secrets.json", FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                   new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                   "user",
                   CancellationToken.None);
```

I am getting the following error

> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not find file
>   'C:\Data\Programs{68788282-E5AD-4D0C-84DA-C5F8EB50D947}\client_secrets.json'

Comment: Shoot in the dark, but can you try `new FileStream("client_secrets.json", ...` As I've tried to open stream in a class in the same root directory it worked for simple file with BuildAction = Content.

Comment: Romasz comment should solve your problem

Comment: Yup it did.. Would you like to post it as answer so that i can accept?

Answer (score 0):

I think your path is broken some way?

This is a wild guess, but does it solve when you try this?

```
string yourpath = Environment.CurrentDirectory + @"\client_secrets.json";

var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                   new FileStream(yourpath, FileMode.Open, FileAccess.Read),
                   new[] { DriveService.Scope.Drive },
                   "user",
                   CancellationToken.None);
```

Comment: I m getting this error Could not find file 'C:\Data\Programs\{68788282-E5AD-4D0C-84DA-C5F8EB50D947}\Install\client_secrets.json'

Comment: No there is no such path like C:\Data in my system

Comment: Where is your client_secrets.json Located?

Comment: inside my project say myproject/client_secret.json